# Facebook-offline_access alternatives: How long will a token created from an app last so I can pull my page's feed into my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

Main Question: 
(since offline_access permission) is deprecating; how long will an access token created by hitting the below url with app's ID and secret last?
    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY
last? It seems a simple question but I have not been able to find a definitive answer here or on developers.facebook.com

Secondary Question
I want to pull my facebook pages's feed into my website (either via jquery plugin or rolling me own), but both using something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100002282383158/feed?method=GET&metadata=true&format=json&callback=___GraphExplorerAsyncCallback___&access_token=XXX
```

basically I'm using an appID and secret created via an fb app that I made just so I can generate an access token and pull my feed into my website (see first question), without requiering the user to authenticate with fb. **Is there a better way to do this than making the above call and creating an app to get a token? (the web server that I have to use can not use php)**

notes:
in this post in the comments it says "Offline access has now been deprecated, but you are allowed to extend an access token to last for 60 days." but I have not found any doc to back that up or a way for me to set that time; and i'd hate to go live wondering if my token will expire at some unknown time
    [Facebook Page Access Tokens - Do these expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696372/facebook-page-access-tokens-do-these-expire)

Comment: From a security perspective, if you put your access token in a url in your website's javascript, then you are exposing it to everyone and you could end up in a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

After the offline_access permission is removed, tokens will last 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an app access token, and they (apparently) do not expire (unless you mess with your password or app secret)

> "App access tokens do not expire unless you refresh you app's App
>   Secret. You do this in your app's settings."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: I think the question was regarding app_tokens that allow apps to post, etc on behalf of a user... not the app_token/app_secret you get when you register your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can get token for user that last 60 days by hiting fallowing url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID& 
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```