# Extending Facebook Page Access Token

Tags: facebook, access-token

i need to extend my facebook access token, I'm calling this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token? 
client_id={MY PAGE ID}&
client_secret={THE SECRET KEY OF MY APP}&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token={AN ACCESS TOKEN FOR MY PAGE}
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
```

I've seen a lot of problem with that access_token, but none answer relative to pages, idk why facebook use api that why... but is the way...

Thank you,

Comment: I also hope that someone from facebook developer team could provide proper solution because we face the same problem now.

Comment: The same here. FB API is like haystack.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get a long-lived access token you need to follow those steps:

1. Create an Application
2. Create a Page (your account need to be "administrator" of the page)
3. Associate the application to the Page (the same way you do it when you want to add a Page Tab to a Page)

   ```
   http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=*YOUR_APP_ID*&pages=1&page=*YOUR_PAGE_ID*
   ```
4. Get a short-lived access token with the permission "manage_pages" associated to your Application.

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=__APP_ID__&scope=manage_pages&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
   then
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=__APP_ID__&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&client_secret=__APP_SECRET__&code=__CODE_FROM_PREVIOUS_REQUEST__
   ```
5. Using the Graph API Explorer with the request [/me/accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/accounts) you can see the access tokens for each Pages that you are administrator. The problem is that those access token are short-lived.
6. Convert your short-lived access token to a long-lived (extending access token):

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=_APP_ID_&client_secret=_APP_SECRET_&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=_ACCESS_TOKEN_ON_STEP_4_
   ```
7. You can now test your new access token with the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=).

Comment: question: My app is not 'tab app' how do i associate it ?

Comment: @siniradam Use this URL: http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=*YOUR_APP_ID*&pages=1&page=*YOUR_PAGE_ID*

Comment: Thanks for that. BTW Yesterday I discovered if I send a request to /me/accounts with long-term token, list returns with long-term tokens.  I've tested with this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=

Comment: Hey @FR6 just wanted to say thanks for the step by step, I sunk quite a bit of time into this the last two days and this guide worked perfectly.

Comment: How do you associate your application to a page?

Comment: Note that `6.` is not needed if the token from `4.` is long lived. If it is, the tokens returned from `/me/accounts` will **never** expire (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extendingpagetokens).

Answer (score 2):

> Scenario 5: Page Access Tokens
>
> When a user grants an app the manage_pages permission, the app is able
>   to obtain page access tokens for pages that the user administers by
>   querying the [User ID]/accounts Graph API endpoint. With the migration
>   enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this
>   endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.
>
> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access
>   token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a
>   long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint
>   will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that
>   a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring
>   user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access
>   permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/