# Post Photo to Facebook Page not associated with User

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a website that will allow any authenticated Facebook user to post photos to a specific album associated with a Facebook page. I am using the JavaScript SDK for this task. This is the code I have so far:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: "492414284132122",
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        channelUrl: "http://wineoclock.dev.mag/ClockMoments/channel.html"
    });
};

function uploadPhoto() {
    console.log("called uploadPhoto()...");
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            document.getElementById("access_token").value = FB.getAuthResponse()["accessToken'];
            var form = document.getElementById("fbPhotoUpload");
            var formData = new FormData(form);
                    // indicate to user that upload is in progress
            document.getElementById("btnUpload").value = "Posting...";
            document.getElementById("btnUpload").disabled = true;
            // post photo to Facebook
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    // post to "Timeline Photos" album
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/283773431737369/photos",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response, status, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("Status: " + status);
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert("Error occured:" + response.error.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("fbPhotoUpload").reset();
                        $("#ThanksModal").reveal();
                    }
                    document.getElementById("btnUpload").value = "Post Photo";
                    document.getElementById("btnUpload").disabled = false;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call error. " + status);
                    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                    console.log("AJAX call complete. " + status);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Login failed: " + response.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Running the code above, I discovered that the selected image gets uploaded, but it is uploaded to Facebook account that is logged in. This is not what I wanted. I wanted to upload it to the target fan page (designated in the AJAX POST request), instead of the logged in user.

I have read on the Internet that I need to request a page access token, instead of a user access token. To do so I would need to log in as the target page, as described in the Facebook doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/).

Is there a way to retrieve the page access token without having to login as the administrator of the Facebook page? If required, can the login be done behind-the-scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I think i misunderstood You; the process described at link i posted results in getting access token for ANY user, you only have to do this once.

I do strongly believe that this is not possible; if it would be doable, practically any app could post at any fanpage.

According to solution from here:[Extending Facebook Page Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183625/extending-facebook-page-access-token), You need have administrator privileges to convert your short-lived page access token to a long-lived (2 months actually instead of couple of hours). The whole process is well described at the link.