# How to get images from my own Instagram with PHP?

Tags: php, sdk, instagram

can somebody tell me please how can I get images from my own Instagram via PHP? I have login name, password, app id, app secret. IG changed the api so all the documentation including how to get access token does not work. I have this peace of code:

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => self::APP_ID_IG,
    'app_secret' => self::APP_SECRET_IG,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);

// This return string which creates access token as "app_id value|app_secret value"
$token = $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken();

// This line throws me an error: 
// Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.
$response = $fb->get('https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=media_url,media_type', $token->getValue());
```

I am lost in it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Instagram's Media API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media)

This endpoint should work to query the user's media: `GET /{ig-user-id}/media` giving you a list of media ids:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "17895695668004550"
    },
    {
      "id": "17899305451014820"
    },
    {
      "id": "17896450804038745"
    },
    {
      "id": "17881042411086627"
    },
    {
      "id": "17869102915168123"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that, I think you sould use the graph API to get the image URL of each media id.

Comment: And how to get user-id if he is not logged in?

Comment: I found user-id so i am going to try it.

Comment: No it does not work. Every request to graph api needs access token. Also this one.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work like this? `$response = $fb->get('https://graph.instagram.com/{user-id}/media', $token->getValue());`

Comment: If not, let me know if this helps you, and I will update the answer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/instagram-media/?locale=es_ES

Comment: Well, it seems like the `/me/media` is correct, but you have to ask permission to the user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media

Also maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183625/extending-facebook-page-access-token

Comment: I dont want to show login window. I need to do it at the background server to server. I have all credentials but cant connect to api. Still some kind of error.

Comment: Well, in some moment you had to get the credentials. You should use that moment to request the correct permissions for your application: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions#step-1--get-authorization

Comment: I dont understand. I sould implement login window run it on the server then get access token for 60 days then remove login window from the code, then rewrite the code with saved token from login and then load it back to server?

Comment: You should learn more about oauth2 authentication method. You do NOT need to create login windows. You should just show window generated by Facebook to end user to let him authorize your application with specific scopes

Comment: Or you could create application with https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password. But I am not sure about this option for Facebook

Answer (score 0):

I created a vuejs adaption a while back, maybe this code structure snippet helps you since I don't have time right now to translate it into `php`, it is written in `javascript` but the API requests remain the same (just use `curl` instead of `axios`): https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1957175

#### General steps:

1. [Get your authorization code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#authorization-codes) either via a Login Window or via a facebook app (described below)
2. `Transform it into a shortterm access token`

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=[CLIENT_ID_HERE]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET_HERE]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI_HERE]&code=[AUTHORIZATION_CODE_HERE]' \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form client_id=[CLIENT_ID_HERE] \
  --form client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET_HERE] \
  --form code=[AUTHORIZATION_CODE_HERE] \
  --form grant_type=authorization_code \
  --form redirect_uri=https://[REDIRECT_URI_HERE]/
```

3. [Transform that into a longterm access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-access-token)

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&access_token=[SHORTTERM_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET_HERE]
```

4. Query the Media Graph endpoint with the URL from my [snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1957175#LC65) using the longterm access token as authorization.
5. Refresh that longterm access token every 60 days ([see my answer on the topic on Github here](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-instagram/issues/34#issuecomment-605962062)). You could totally automate that step via for example via CRON.

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/refresh_access_token?grant_type=ig_refresh_token&access_token=[OLD_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE]
```

For more info about which field to add to the query check the [official facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media#fields)

---

#### Getting an authorization code via a facebook app:

1. Log into your [facebook developer account](https://developers.facebook.com/)
2. Create a new Application
3. Under products, add `Instagram Basic Display` and fill out all necessary fields

[image: Instagram Basic Display]

4. Within the section `Basic Display` of the `Instagram Basic Display` product you will find your `App ID` and `Secret`
   [image: App ID and Secret]
5. Below that you can enter your `redirect_uri`

[image: redirect_uri]

6. Finally below that is the User Token Generator which you can use to

> [...]quickly generate long-lived Instagram User Access Tokens for any of your public Instagram accounts. This is useful if you [...] don’t want to bother with implementing the Authorization Window [...] [See Instagram Basic Display API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview/#user-token-generator)

7. Continue with **3.** of General Steps

Comment: First step says:  To get an Authorization Code, implement the Authorization Window into your app. After an app user authenticates their identity through the window and grants your app any permissions it needs, we will redirect the user to your app and include an Authorization Code.... I dont want to show any windows. I am the owner. I need the pictures without the authorisation windows. Server to server solution.