# Facebook long lived token doesn't expire anymore?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it just me or long lived access tokens for Facebook API don't expire anymore?

We used to get a "expires" parameter when we exchanged the short-live to a long-lived token which was of 60 days. But since few days, we don't receive this anymore.

Plus, when we are looking at the debugger for those tokens (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token) it's says "Expires: Never".

I can't find official documentation on this whether those token are now really never expiring. Any idea?

Thanks,

Stéphane

**Update**

Page access token (manage_page permission) does not expire: "By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages." https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a Facebook Page Access Token? If yes, there is some great answers here: [Facebook Page Access Tokens - Do these expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696372/facebook-page-access-tokens-do-these-expire)

Comment: That's correct, we ask for manage_pages permission. SO I guess you are right and I'm not crazy. Page access token does not expire "By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages." https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token

Comment: @Steph - do you know if this never expiring token will also work to fetch the user's stream (or other public streams)? I could wait two months to try, but would rather have a faster answer. thx

Comment: If it has been mixed with the right set of permission, I think so. But it's still fuzzy. Some of my users still have expiring tokens. Others don't so you should handle both scenarios.