# Can't delete an article by Facebook Instant Article API's DELETE method

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles

I have an id of created article and I also can get the status of the article by GET method:

```
{article_id}?access_token={access_token}
```

I get a response like:

```
{
  "id": {article_id},
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

But when I try to delete the article by the DELETE method with the same params I'm getting this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#240) Requires a valid user to be specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 240,
    "fbtrace_id": "GsXXXXBjq"
  }
}
```

Everything was done according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api#delete).

I'm using `v2.6` graph version whit this permissions:

```
publish_pages, pages_manage_instant_articles, manage_pages
```

I use a page token that do not expire, I got it by [@Simon.Ponder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696372/facebook-page-access-tokens-do-these-expire).

I have the only one admin user for the application and the page.

How can it be solved?

Comment: What type of token did you use?

Comment: @CBroe I use a page token that do not expire.

Comment: Just curious, it could be that the endpoint was not correctly documented. Try `DELETE /{page-id}/instant_articles/{article-id}`. This [part of the graph api docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/instant_articles/#Deleting) conflicts with the other link you shared

Comment: Is it possible you need additional permissions to issue DELETE requests?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mix up your `{article-id}` and `{access_token}`? :P

Comment: I have similar issue, but the response for me is:  [message] => (#200) User cannot access this application . I've created the article with the same user and the same long-lived access token

Comment: @Quirk Thank you very much for your comment. I was  mixing up article_id with ID that I get from Facebook API after posting the article.

Comment: @whitesiroi You should probably write an answer describing what fixed your issue and accept it.

Comment: @Quirk I still haven't solved it:) I'm getting a new error "(#240) Requires a valid user to be specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to delete post by using [facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php/)

```
     $client = Client::create(
                     $this->options->app_id,
                     $this->options->app_secret,
                     $this->options->access_token,
                     $this->options->page_id,
                     true);

     try {
             $client->removeArticle($my_canonical_url)
     } catch (Exception $e) {
             throw $e->getMessage();
     }
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you are saying after posting your article you are getting response like this

```
{
  "id": {article_id},
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

But this is not `article_id` this is `import_status_id`. So

```
{
      "id": {import_status_id},
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

With `import_status_id` you can get `article_id` using [this api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api#importstatus) if your articles is posted successfully. then you can delete your article using  [delete api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api#delete) as usual. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you mate for your help.